# IONIC : How to create file json and used as database

Tags: json, ionic-framework, offline

i need to create a file data format json

and used as localstorage :read and write

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

To store data:

```
window.localStorage.setItem( ‘app-name’, JSON.stringify(appData));
```

To get data:

```
var appData = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem( ‘app-name’ ));
```

app-name is the key and you can change it to whatever name you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  but max size of localStorage  5MB on ipad.I Need a solution that replaces.